# Cannot pass variable in Private sub BackgroundWorker

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker

Hi I'm having trouble with Backgroundworker. I have a sub and I want to pass some variable in 
that sub(BackgroundWorker). It says that Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork cannot handle event Public Event DoWork because they do not have compatible signature. Here's the code

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal strArrDetails As String, ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
```

It seems that when I put ByVal strArrDetails As String into the argument,BackgroundWorker1.DoWork will turn out as error. Is there a way pass the variable into the sub?

Please be nice to me as I'm still learning vb.net